# Nginx + js server

Tags: nginx, react-router

I have a very simple js server (w/ webpack) serving a simple client-side app. My configuration file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /home/user/project/dist;
    index index.html;

    server_name project.example.com;

    location / { 
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

I have tried many combinations of `try_files`. I don't want it to 404 when it can't find something other than `index.html` (which is what it currently does). It works OK for the root (pointing the browser to `project.example.com`, but anything else gives a 404.

To solve this, I've tried to set `try_files` in many combinations, such as:

`try_files $uri index.html;`
`try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;`
`try_files $uri /absoulute/path/to/index.html;`

They either 404 everything or give a 500, which, according to nginx logs, is an infinite redirect loopback.

I don't think what I'm doing is terribly complex, but everything I've tried so far hasn't done what I want, which is to allow `react-router` to take care of everything by having `try_files` just give everything to `index.html`.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nginx` URIs contain a leading `/`. If the URI `http://project.example.com/index.html` works, then the `try_files` statement should look like:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Clearly I didn't try every combination. :) Many thanks!